# Excel xml spreadsheet - is it possible to embed images?

Tags: .net, xml, excel

I'm trying to export data from a web app into excel, but there is a request to include the company's logo at the top of the spreadsheet. My normal method of creating the excel is to create a spreadsheet in excel and save it as an Xml Spreadsheet (Excel 2003). This allows me to build up the xml in code.

However, when attempting to save the excel worksheet as an xml worksheet I get warned that the image will be lost.

So, is it possible to embed an image from my application? I tried base64, but that didn't work.

`<Data ss:Type="Base64">base64string here...</Data>` isn't valid

Html isn't interpreted either. Is this possible?

Excel 2003 + is the target.

Comment: Switch to .XLSX Open Office type files (Excel 2007)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that 2003 plus is the target.

Comment: have you found any solution for insert images in excel, i am creating excel same way as you have used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying do the same export.
And I'm stuck solving this problem too.
But I've bad news, as MSDN describes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_ss%3adata) , the only ss:Type possible are:

```
Enumeration—Number, DateTime, Boolean, String, and Error
```

If you can open the .xls might this solution help you:
http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/11/10/how-to-insert-multiple-images-in-excel-open-xml/

Unfortunately, for me I still with no solution.

Comment: Yes, this is now possibly targeting 2007+ - I've done this somewhere, but I can't track down any code, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you create Excel workbooks with embedded images (and [more](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/products/spreadsheetgear.net.aspx)).

You can see the "Excel Report with Picture" sample on the [ASP.NET Excel Reporting](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) samples page and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer the question!