# Insert picture into excel using XSLT

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am importing a XML-File to excel using a custom `xsl-stylesheet` (XSLT1.0).

The XML-File is containing an URL to an image-file (`.jpg-picture`)

Now I want to insert this picture into a cell.
Is this possible to do so via the `xslt-file`? For example by inserting vba-code into it (Is this possible?)? I did not find a direct solution..

Looks like nobody have done this before..

Is there a way to achieve this using the Office Open XML SpreadsheetML?

Comment: If you are using Spreadsheet XML 2003, then I don't think embedding images is supported. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200056/excel-xml-spreadsheet-is-it-possible-to-embed-images

Comment: Try to generate such a xml containing an (probably referenced, not embedded) image from excel itself and then inspect how the xml code looks like, then synthesize that using xslt.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic width="100%"
 content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"
     src="yourfile.jpg">
    </fo:external-graphic>

 </fo:block>
```